# Java : Saving uploaded png image 

Tags: java, graphics, image-processing, awt

I am having issue when i save a png file uploaded by user . It loses its transparency . Here is how I save it .

```
 ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        ProgressListenerImpl listener = new ProgressListenerImpl();
        UploadProgressBar uop = new UploadProgressBar(listener);

        List<FileItem> fileItemsList = upload.parseRequest(request);

        for(FileItem fi : fileItemsList) {
///get name etc.
    File fNew= new File(fileLocation, justName);
            fi.write(fNew);
        }
```

it puts a black background . Any other way to save  it as png  ?

Comment: Can you supply the full code? What is fi?

Comment: ... is the image getting processed first in any way? Had a similar problem when resizing and saving an image in a web app scenario.

Comment: The updated code still doesn't help. We don't know what a FileItem is or what your custom write(...) method does. That is where the problem will be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating a BufferedImage on the server side, make sure you create it as a type that supports the alpha channel, e.g.

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
```

Paul